# How do I set a default sort order for an NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa

I've got a cocoa app that's got a TableView with bindings to a model through an NSArrayController.

The app works as I want, but the default sort order of the table is wrong.

[buildwatch http://public.west.spy.net/BuildWatch.png](http://public.west.spy.net/BuildWatch.png)

I typically start the program and click on the last header twice to get it sorting the right way.  Is there a way in the nib/bindings/whatever to specify the default sort order, or to programatically tell it to do what would happen if I clicked there twice?  Or even just remember the previous sort order?

Answer (score 7):

Look at [NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can set it up using -setSortDescriptors: on the NSTableView. Or you can put the sort descriptors in an ivar and bind them with the Sort Descriptor binding in IB.

Answer (score 5):

I typically do this sort of thing in -windowDidLoad.  Suppose your `NSWindowController` subclass has the IBOutlet _arrayController set to the NSArrayController in question, and that your model possesses the property buildETA:

```
NSSortDescriptor *buildETASortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"buildETA" ascending:NO];
[_arrayController setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:buildETASortDescriptor]];
[buildETASortDescriptor release];
```

Edit: Changed -awakeFromNib to -windowDidLoad since this is a hypothetical `NSWindowController` subclass

Comment: This doesn't seem to update the view to indicate that it's sorted that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create this custom class and then in InterfaceBuilder select your ArrayController and change Custom Class in the Indentity Inspector to your CustomArrayController

```
#import "CustomArrayController.h"
@implementation PatchbayArrayController

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSSortDescriptor *mySortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"propertyNameHere" ascending:YES];
    [self setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mySortDescriptor]];
    [mySortDescriptor release]; 
}
@end
```

Comment: Subclassing just to set the sort descriptors seems like overkill compared to the workable solutions already presented. Is there some advantage to doing it this way?